# TextField mui component autoFocus end of text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autofocus

Right now, `autoFocus` applies to the beginning of the input but I'd like to get focused on the end of the text.

```
export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    "hello world. hello world. hello world"
  );

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" }
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        variant="outlined"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        multiline
        autoFocus
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Is this possible?

I tried this from this link : https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/12779
But this didn't work for my case.

```
<TextField
    variant="outlined"
    type="text"
    id="field-comment"
    name="comment"
    label="Label"
    placeholder="Placeholder"
    onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
    inputRef={(input) => input && input.focus()}
    onFocus={(e) =>
        e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(
        e.currentTarget.value.length,
        e.currentTarget.value.length
    )}
    multiline
    rows={4}
    value={value}
    className={classes.sCommentTextField}
/>
```

I also tried this.

```
<TextField
  inputRef={input => input && input.focus()}
/>
```

but it also didn't work.

Are there any ways that I can do this?

Comment: Works for me https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-dust-h6z85o?file=/src/Input.js

Comment: You are right. I added `inputRef` and `onFocus` and didn't remove `autoFocus`. Thank you! now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works!

```
<TextField
    variant="outlined"
    type="text"
    id="field-comment"
    name="comment"
    label="Label"
    placeholder="Placeholder"
    onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
    inputRef={(input) => input && input.focus()}
    onFocus={(e) =>
        e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(
        e.currentTarget.value.length,
        e.currentTarget.value.length
    )}
    multiline
    rows={4}
    value={value}
    className={classes.sCommentTextField}
/>
```

Remove `autoFocus` and add `inputRef` and `onFocus`